# export to csv from neo4j using import-cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I found this neo4j data exporting tool (https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#cypher-import) and it worked perfectly on my mac OS computer. I followed the same step to export data from a ubuntu server and the following error message was generated without further explanations.

Has anyone used this tool on ubuntu and any idea what the error message may indicate? Also, is there another way to export large (~100M rows) neo4j data into a csv file?

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ import-cypher -d"," -o test.csv match (p:Product)-[s:SIMILAR_TO]-(q:Product)  return p.Id,q.Id limit 10
Query: match (p:Product)-[s:SIMILAR_TO]-(q:Product)  return p.Id,q.Id limit 10 infile (none) delim ',' quoted false outfile test.csv batch-size 1000
Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService.execute(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/Result;
```

Comment: does the version of `neo4j-shell` match the version running on the server?

Comment: Ah, that was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just added a new way of exporting data as cypher statements.

https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#cypher-export

(Note this is for Neo4j 2.2.5)

But for 100M rows I think `import-cypher -o` is still a good approach.

Otherwise check out: http://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/